# Arrays the same keys need combine their value

Tags: php, arrays

After loop value from my db, I got array output like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 3
        [6] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [1] => 2
        [6] => 2
    )
.
.
.
more


)
```

What I want, is which arrays have the same key need to sum their value:

Ex:

```
[0] => array (
           [1] => 2
           [6] => 1
         )
[1] => array (
           [1] => 2
           [6] => 2
         )
.
.
.
```

There are two key are the same

I want the result like that:

```
array (
           [1] => 4 // after sum value
           [2] => 3 // no duplicated key
           [6] => 3 // after sum value
           .
           .
           .
  )
```

Someone can help me please!

Comment: How to construct the array is under your control. You should share the code you done.

Answer (score 2):

A simple [foreach loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) or two can solve this problem:

```
$totals = array();
foreach($array as $current) {
    foreach($current as $key => $value) {
        if(!array_key_exists($key, $totals))
            $totals[$key] = 0;

        $totals[$key] += $value;
    }
}

print_r($totals);
```

Comment: Thank you scrowler, you done for me :D

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if it provides a solution.

Comment: how to accept the answer on stackoverflow?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tour